# AdMob Mediation with iAd

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, iad

I have a Universal iPhone/iPad application for which I am using AdMob Mediation. I would like to request an iAd first, and then an AdMob if the iAd fails. I have the eCPM setting for iAd at $1.00 and AdMob at $0.20. However, I am getting an iAd fill rate of about 20%. I have tried numerous different eCPM settings without sucess. Before integrating AdMob Mediation in a recent app update, I was only using iAds and getting an iAd fill rate of about 99%.

Is this happening because I am using a Smart Banner? From what I understand, iAd does support the Smart Banner. My app only supports Portrait Mode and the Smart Banner uses a size of 320x50 for iPhone and 768x90 for iPad. However, according to Apple's iAd Programming Guide, an iAd is 768x66 for an iPad.

Is the incorrect Smart Banner size causing the iAds to fail for iPads? Based on my iTunes Sales reports, I have more iPad users than iPhone users. What is the best solution for this problem? Should I stop using a Smart Banner, or should I programmatically change the size of the GADBannerView if the device is an iPad?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to import `iAd`, import `AdMob SDK` (`GADBannerView.h`) and add

`ADBannerView *iAd;` in your .h file;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initBanner];
}

- (void)initBanner {

    iAd = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    iAd.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    [self.view addSubview:iAd];

    NSLog(@"iAd Loading...");
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    iAd.hidden = YES;

    NSLog(@"iAd Failed... Going With AdMob");

    GADBannerView *gAd = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    gAd.adUnitID = @"Your ID";
    gAd.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:gAd];
    [gAd loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}
```

Comment: So I would use this code to handle the mediation with my own code instead of having AdMob to do it for me? And would this code go in my ViewController? Also, I'll need to check if the device is an iPhone or iPad in order to set the correct size of the banner right?

Comment: Saw some outdated code... Sorry. Will fix it now. @Shan

Comment: but I still need to check whether the device is an iPad or iPhone right?

Comment: No, why should you do that @Shan?

Comment: Because it's a universal app. Wouldn't I want a bigger banner on the iPad?

Comment: Wiklunds `currentContentSizeIdentifier` has been deprecated as of iOS 6. Do I replace it with `[adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];` ?

Comment: @Shan I think Portrait is default. If you want Portrait just remove the code.

Comment: Just wanted to say, I've done A LOT of searching on an effective solution for this and with a little tweaking, this works PERFECTLY. Thank you!